# Как удалить все буквы кроме первой в notepad++?

Tags: регулярные-выражения, notepad++

Как удалить все буквы кроме первой **в первом слове** всех строк используя Notepad++?

Comment: Найти `^(\w)\w+`, заменить на `\1`.

Comment: Лучше все же `^(.).*$` заменить на `$1` наверное

Comment: Возможно. Я воспринял `слово` как набор словесных символов.

Comment: Проведите примеры строк, там кроме слов что ещё может быть? Могут быть перед словами какие-то ведущие символы - не слова?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Найти `^(\w)\w*` и заменить на `\1`:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Это должно работать.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin Большое спасибо! [Текущая версия](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/580435) была предложена [носителем языка](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/56547101); надеюсь, она верна.